# Making a multi functions file

Tags: php

Ok, I'm in the middle of making a multi function php file.
The file is named functions.php and has switch - case.

At first, I just have a simple register.php file which sends to functions.php.
Here's the error which I get :-

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\transfer\functions.php on line 5
```

functions.php?username=223&password=223&action=register

This is pretty unsecure..I just want to show the action..like functions.php?action=register

What changes do I make to my script ?
Here's the code :-

register.php

```
<form action="functions.php" name="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username : </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password : </td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'akshay!@#') or die (mysql_error($db));
mysql_select_db('transfer', $db);
switch($_POST['action'])
{
case 'register':
        $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
        $password=(isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
        $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username, $db);
        $password = md5($password);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
        $query = "select * from users where user_name = '" . $username . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
                    echo "Username already exists, redirecting";
                    header('Refresh: 3; URL=register.php');
                    die();
                }

                if(empty($username) || empty($password))
                {
                    echo "Fields cannot be empty, redirecting";
                    header('Refresh: 3; URL=register.php');
                }
                else
                {
                    $query2 = "insert into users(user_id, user_name, user_pass)
                              values
                              (NULL, '" . $username . "', '" . $password . "')";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
                    if($result2)
                    {
                        echo "Registration successful";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Cannot register";
                    }
                }
                break;
    }           

 ?>
```

Comment: Add a hidden field. `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />`

Comment: You may want to consider changing your root MySQL user's password now that you've published it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the **query string** ("functions.php?username=223&password=223&action=register"), it looks like you're using `GET` to send the data, and not `POST`.

You should be looking for `$_GET['action']` instead, and you should use

```
isset($_GET['action'])
```

to check if the action is set.

### Edit

If you're set on using `POST`, which you really should be for this type of application, then you'll need to change your form:

```
<form action="functions.php" name="post" method="post">
```

Additionally, you'll want to use a **hidden field** for the `action` parameter instead of using the submit button:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
```

The `method="POST"` attribute ensures that your data will be transmitted to `functions.php` using `POST`. This way the data won't show up in the URL.

Then, your `functions.php` can contain:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'register':
            $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
            // And so on
    }
}
else {
    echo "No action specified.";
}
```

Comment: Tried that..still can see all the information in the address bar.

Comment: This worked.Thanks @theftprevention
Ok, suppose now I create a login.php file..then do I should have these two lines right ? 
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>

And the another case 'login': in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

It means that `$_POST['action']` isn't set.

In your example you pass it in the URL, so should be using `$_GET['action']` instead.

Comment: Says user already exists + I can still see the username and password as clear text in the address bar.

Comment: You can't test it like that - the parameters don't go in the address bar.